# Error: self signed certificate in Node JS Client

Tags: node.js, linux, ssl, https, self-signed

Example Program:

> Server:

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var https = require('https'); 
var options = { 
    key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'), 
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server-crt.pem'), 
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem'), 
}; 
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) { 
    console.log(new Date()+' '+ 
        req.connection.remoteAddress+' '+ 
        req.method+' '+req.url); 
    res.writeHead(200); 
    res.end("hello world\n"); 
}).listen(4433);
```

> Client:

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var https = require('https'); 
var options = { 
    hostname: 'localhost', 
    port: 4433, 
    path: '/', 
    method: 'GET', 
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem') 
}; 
var req = https.request(options, function(res) { 
    res.on('data', function(data) { 
        process.stdout.write(data); 
    }); 
}); 
req.end();
```

I have generated the Keys and certificate using openssl in my Linux server.
But while running client program its showing as **Error: self signed certificate** . By referring some websites and even stack overflow discussions some have mentioned that using a option called **rejectUnauthorized: false** even though there is no use in using this parameter while using certificates for secure transfer of data.

- Is there any way to trust the **certificates in Linux server**?
- Any **example program** with certificates and node JS Program ?
- **Node JS Client** to connect to server?
- Without Using **rejectUnauthorized: false**?

Comment: Do you just want the client to ignore the self signed cert error? If so, set `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"` at the top of your client. Obviously not a good idea in production.

Comment: I need in Production environment..Please help.

Comment: In production, you should be dealing with valid certificates, rather than self signed ones. If you need it to, the above line would work in production though.

Comment: @ManuCRajan did you manage to solve it? Having exactly the same issue...